# How can display a little KML 3.5MB file on Google Maps but with around of 1 million of Points

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-earth

I have a little problem, I'm work on a map with politic division, but when I try to load the KML file in Google Earth work fine, then I publish this KML and I try to use them in Google Maps, but not work, I read that Google Map have some restrictions, like size of files, and limit of Points, but then How I can display correctly my Map, I also have the data in a DataBase.

In this moment, I'm using FusionTables and work very well, but in my job don't want use FusionTables.

I have some option? (Server Side Processing, Load some KML instead of one or something)

thanks in advance.

Excuse me for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

1. try a KMZ file (raw KML in a KMZ can be bigger, up to 10MB)
2. use a third party KML parser (no limits on size, but may have performance problems)
3. break your KML into multiple files that meet the restrictions.

[KML reference on limits](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport), looks  to me like a KMZ (compressed KML) file will work for the data you have described.

```
Maximum fetched file size (raw KML, raw GeoRSS, or compressed KMZ)   3MB
Maximum uncompressed KML file size                                  10MB
```